# How to write the If statements for different urls based on the url variable?

Tags: php, url, if-statement, get, statements

While working on my website today, I came across this -

Site url is -

```
http://url.com/?age={age}
```

I use the GET function to pass the variable -

```
<?php  
$age = $_GET['age'];   
?>
```

I have a url on this page but I want to change it based on the visitor age, for example -

0-20 years old --->    http://url.com/teenagers/

21-40 years old ---->  http://url.com/adults/

40+ years old ---->  http://url.com/matures/

I have the following code in mind -

```
<?php 
if ($age <= '20')
{
 echo '<a href="http://url.com/teenagers/">URL</a>';
} 
else if($age >= '40') 
{
 echo '<a href="http://url.com/matures/">URL</a>';
} 
else{
    echo '<a href="http://url.com/adults/">URL</a>';
}
?>
```

I'm not even sure if the code is correct, when I append some random letters (not numbers), it points to http://url.com/matures/ instead of http://url.com/adults/. And if I don't append anything after the age variable, I get pointed to http://url.com/teenagers/.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can add a isNumeric function before starting the if and wrap everything into it.

Comment: Ah, and take out the '20' put 20 it's a number, not a string you need to check.

Comment: Study it thoroughly http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of your code you are comparing strings not numbers. Strings are always compared in alphabetical order so `'b' > 'a'` and `'a' > '1'`. That is why you get the result `matures` for non-numeric strings.

As other suggest you should just drop the quotes in the `if` statements to issue a numeric comparison. PHP will then try to translate your string to a number and compare the two as numbers.

If you let your users put anything in the `age` parameter you should take this into consideration in your code:

```
<?php if (
          null !== $age  // make sure the `age` parameter is not left empty
          && is_numeric($age) // make sure it's a number
          && $age < 20
       ) {
           ...
       } elseif ($age > 40) { 
           // if the age is empty or is not a number it will never be bigger than
           // a numeric 40
           ...
       } else {
           // this will cover all other cases so:
           // - empty `age`
           // - non-numeric `age`
           // - `age` between 20 and 40 (inclusive) 
           ...
       }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if `$age` will be a string and you will check like:

```
if($age && $age <= 20)
```

In this case $age will be equal 1, because, look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php)

Second. You need to check 20 or 40 not like string('20', '40' ). Dot this:

```
 if (is_numeric($age)) {  
     $var = "";
     if ($age <= 20) {            
           $var = 'teenagers';            
     } else if ($age >= 40) { 
           $var = 'matures';              
     } else {
           $var = 'adults';           
     } 

     echo '<a href="http://url.com/'.$var.'/">URL</a>';
}
```

If $age is not intger you can redirect to some another page

Before this checking you can check if $age even integer(because someone can set in url not int) using [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric)

Comment: Well, you can wrap everything inside a is_numeric function for security purpose and return an error, can't you?

Comment: Eh).Did it.Thanks. OP:  think about how optimize this code in future

Comment: You can even optimize it a lot more. All the "echo" have the same text outside of some words. You can put the word changed as a var and then concat if outside the if.

Comment: It was rejected by( I paste the you changes, Thank

Comment: Another thing you can do is as another question says, to check that var is != null and is numeric and not only is numeric.

Comment: Eh, add. Hope it will help OP)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$age = 40;
if ($age <= 20) {
    echo '<a href="http://url.com/teenagers/">URL</a>';
} else if ($age >= 40) {
    echo '<a href="http://url.com/matures/">URL</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="http://url.com/adults/">URL</a>';
}
?>
```

You just need to remove the quotes around the string. Assuming your string is just numerical